# check for indented string

Tags: c#, regex, readline

I am parsing an .ini file and I need to target an exact section. The .ini file looks like this and I am trying to target the section "2nd Section" and not continue on:

```
1st Section
    item1
    item2
    item3
2nd Section
    item1
    item2
    item3
3rd Section
    item1
    item2
    item3
```

Here is the code I have so far to target the section header "1st String"

```
    private static string ParseSataHeader(string sataHeader, string bcuFileName)
    {
        string strLine = "";
        StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader(bcuFileName);
        bool foundSection = false;

        while (strLine !=null)
        {
            strLine = myReader.ReadLine();
            if (strLine !=null)
            {
               if (String.Compare("2nd Section", strLine, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                    sataHeader = strLine.Trim();
            }
```

In VBS i know that you can do a RegExpression function in order to keep iterating until you find a string that is not indented. Any ideas?

Comment: you mean this http://regex101.com/r/hI8vY0/1 ?

Comment: try this http://regex101.com/r/dU4yE6/1

Comment: I had a somewhat similar task so I created a [MadMilkman.Ini](https://github.com/MarioZ/MadMilkman.Ini) library for this. I need to point out that you can actually retrieve an information about INI sections or items indentation for example: "file.Sections["2nd Section"].LeftIndentation" or "file.Sections["2nd Section"].Keys["item1"].LeftIndentation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this INI parser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/646296/A-Cross-platform-Csharp-Class-for-Using-INI-Files) written for C#. I believe it would be good if you use some parser instead of regex engine or some string split etc.

Comment: What, use a parser? [Why would you want to suggest that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)? +1

Answer (score 0):

Using the [ini-parser](https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser) library is a piece of cake

```
// Parse the ini file
IniData parsedData = new FileIniDataParser.LoadFile("ini_file_path.ini");

// Get an specific value inside that section ...
var value = parsedData["2nd Section"]["item1"]

// ... or just iterate to get all values for that section
foreach(KeyData key in parsedData["2nd Section"].Keys)
   Console.WriteLine(key.Name + " = " + key.Value);
```

Disclaimer: I'm the creator of ini-parser